# Accessing instance variables of a parent class, from its child

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

I have been learning Objective C for the iPhone for some weeks now, and today got my provisioning profile through, so wanated to put my app on my phone. However when I built it for my iPhone I got a list of errors (almost identical) of the type:

```
error: 'itemPickerView' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

When I built this for the simulator, this does not happen.

The errors all happen in a single class implementation file (ProjectSettingsController) which extends DetailController.

I have 2 other classes that also extend DetailController, and make use of the same instance variables as ProjectSettingsController does, but they do not cause errors.

ProjectSettingsController is slightly different, as the view it manages is never directly added to the navigation controller, however the compiler wouldnt know this at the time, and it works correctly on the simulator (both running IOS 4.3)

I guess my question is two fold:

1. Why would something give me a compiler error when compiling for a device, and not when compiling for the simulator?
2. Why is it giving me this error at all, only on this one class?

Here is the .h for DetailController

```
@interface DetailController :      UITableViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>  {
    NSMutableDictionary * data;
    NSMutableArray * dataOrder;
    NSMutableDictionary * objectToData;
    UIDatePicker * pickerView;
    UIPickerView * itemPickerView;
    UIBarButtonItem * doneButton;
    UIBarButtonItem  *  savedRightButton;
    UIBarButtonItem  *  savedLeftButton;
    UIBarButtonItem * insertButton;
    UIView * slidingView;
    UITextView * textView;
    BOOL isEditing;
}
```

Here is the .h for ProjectSettingsController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "Project.h"
#import "Task.h"
@class ProjectController;

@interface ProjectSettingsController : DetailController{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ProjectController* parent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController * navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationItem * navigationItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Project* project;
```

ProjectController is declared as a class, as opposed to included, as it already includes this class. I have tried adding DetailController as @class it did nothing, as I expected it would.

Here is a snippet of an offending piece of code from ProjectSettingsController.m

```
int hours = [itemPickerView selectedRowInComponent: 0] + 1;
```

Here is the .h for TaskController which works correctly

```
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "Task.h"
#import "Project.h"
#import "CompletionSlider.h"

@interface TaskController : DetailController{

}
```

And here is a snippet of code from TaskController.m that works.

```
[itemPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]+1]
```

I have gone over the ins and outs of the two files for about 2 hours now, and can't find any reason why this would be happening.

Should I change the code to use properties, which would then meen going through my code and putting a super. in front of all of these variables? It seems silly to not be able to access instance variables from within a child class (especially since I seem to be able to access the methods?!)

I look forward to being told what silly thing it is that I have missed

Comment: `self.` not `super.`....  Also, Objective-C has "instance variables", not "member variables".  A nit, but it'll help you read docs, etc,to keep it straight.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, but as the instance variables belong to the parent class, not the class itself, should it not be super.? I know that self. would work too.

Comment: I don't know why this is not working, but in general I try to avoid accessing ivars directly, especially superclass ivars. If I were you, I would turn all of those ivars into declared properties, remove the ivars declarations, and use synthesized accessors/ivars instead.

Comment: @Zack Newsham: `super` not a separate thing from `self` — they're both ways of referring to the current object. The only difference between writing `super` and `self` is that, when you use `super` as the receiver of a message (e.g. `[super doSomething]`), the runtime skips methods implemented in the current class when trying to resolve the message into a method call. It is meaningless to write `super` outside of a message send.

Comment: Can you show more of the context around the offending snippet from ProjectSettingsController.m? Are you trying to reference `itemPickerView` outside the `ProjectSettingsController` class implementation? I don't know why you'd get the error for device but not simulator... like if there's a way that ProjectSettingsController could get left out of the build.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you change the build to target Simulator or Devices, you change the source of system header files you #import or #include.  The differences in those header files may account for the change between simulator or device builds.

Whenever you suddenly get a list of compile errors, focus on the first error.  Often a single error can cause further errors that cascade quickly into a huge list. Sometimes fixing the first error fixes all the rest.